# javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException - get stacktrace for origin

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, openjpa, openejb

In my web application I use OpenJPA. Sometimes when I make database operation I get this exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a synchronization
```

with root case:

```
org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.SetRollbackOnlyException: setRollbackOnly() called.  See stacktrace for origin
```

The question is: how to get stacktrace for exception which was thrown in transaction?

I look here

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GERONIMO-4576
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENEJB-782
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENEJB-980

but I don't understand it.

I think I get this exception every time when I try to save big file (more than 2MB) to the table at database.

Comment: I think you should catch exceptions from certain EJBs and throw them further, instead of trying to do other EntityManager operations. As of EJB spec, if using an container-manager transcation-scoped EntityManager, if any exceptions occur (except some related to `query.getSingleResult()`), the transaction is automatically rolled-back, which is probably your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to set this `properties` inside your `persistece.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="laudoweb_pu">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/integracaolaudoweb</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.xxx.xxxEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="oracle" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
            <property name="openjpa.AutoDetach" value="close" />
            <property name="openjpa.DetachState" value="loaded" />
            <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="false" />
            <property name="openjpa.Optimistic" value="true" />
            <property name="openjpa.Multithreaded" value="true" />
            <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.NontransactionalRead" value="true" />
            <property name="openjpa.RestoreState" value="all" />
            <property name="openjpa.ManagedRuntime" value="auto" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here the `openjpa` documentation for `logs` and other `properties`.

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/ref_guide_logging_openjpa.html

Mainly this line is important for **log** and **trace**:

```
 <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
```